# Use of generics in Exceptions

Tags: c#, generics, exception

So my question will sound like a discussion but it's not.
I'm looking for sources on the topic but I can't seem to find many.

Here I go, in .Net, it is possible to create a generic exception and catch it, ie.

```
class MyException<T> : Exception { }
// ...
catch(MyException<int> e) { }
```

But I notice that I can't find any use of that in the framework or in big libraries.

So my question is, Where can I find information/discussions on that matter, should you use exceptions with generics, should you avoid it?

The reason I'm asking this is because in many scenarios that I've encountered, it feels right from the thrower's perspective to throw an exception with details in it that use a generic but it feels dirty from the catcher's perspective to catch an exception with a generic in it.

Maybe I'm being too zealous about code practices but I'd really like to find some source material on that matter.

Comment: yes it can be done.  I wouldn't do it that way.

Comment: Ask yourself the following question: what would generics offer you that you'd consider an undeniable advantage? I can't think of any to be honest.

Comment: It mostly applies to working with generic classes, ie. a KeyNotFoundException<TKey> when working with a Dictionar<TKey, TValue>. Or when the thrower wants to add data to the exception and that data contains generics

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the main reason is that exceptions are not bound to types, they relate more to a failed action/usage so to speak.

There isn't any need for things like `ArgumentNullException<string>` or an `OverflowException<int>` and an `OveflowException<long>`, the non generic versions suffice.

What you are proposing simply doesn't add any value and it just adds more clutter with additional exception types you need to be handling; remember `OverflowException<int>` and `OveflowException<long>` would be different types, you'd need to catch both in a method where any of the two can happen.

Also, any performance arguments don't really apply. If you are catching an exception and unwinding the stack, any boxing going on is the least of your worries...

All in all, it just seems like a useless approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example for you from a 'big' library: WCF

[FaultException<TDetail>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576199(v=vs.110).aspx)

The point of this is that a client of a WCF service may not be written in .Net and so may not understand Exceptions. However, the clients will understand a fault object - but .Net doesn't let you throw any old object so WCF provides a generic FaultException that you can specialise with your fault type. When you throw one of these exceptions, WCF will extract the fault object and serialise it back to the client.

This is a very special case - allowing faults to be returned to non .Net clients while still allowing the .Net developer to use exceptions. I'm not sure what other use case you would have that would require a generic exception but there is a precedent.

Edit:
The above could also be achieved by a single non-generic FaultException class wrapping an arbitrary object in its constructor. But FaultException is generic  so that, if the client is a .Net WCF client then WCF will turn it back into a FaultException of the correct type and allow the client to catch the specific type of fault object e.g.

```
try
{
  service.DoSomething();
}
catch(FaultException<FaultType1>)
{}
catch(FaultException<FaultType2>)
{}
```

This allows client and server to be written in a symmetrical and (somewhat) familiar manner.